# How to put glyphicon inside cakephp submit form?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, form-submit, glyphicons

The code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>', array('class' => array('btn btn-danger')), array('escape' => false)); ?>
```

Instead of glyphicon it shows just text:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements), you can't use `escape` with Submit- you have to use Button instead and specify that it's a submit button:

```
echo $this->Form->button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>', array(
    'type' => 'submit', 
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger', 
    'escape' => false
));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Form->submit()` should take two options, a caption and an array of options. You are passing it the caption plus two arrays. Also I don't think in this case you need to wrap these options within sub-arrays.

Try this:

```
echo $this->Form->submit('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>',
     array('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'escape' => false)
);
```